# Converges of measures.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Good afternoon, we have the following:

Let $(Y,d)$ is a general metric space, $\mathcal{M}(Y)$ is the set of finite Borel measures on $Y$ and $C_B(Y)$ denotes the Banach space of bounded continuous functions on $Y$, equipped with the metric $||f||=\sup_Y|f|$. Then a sequence $\{\mu_n\}\in\mathcal{M}(Y)$ converges weak star to $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(Y)$ if $\mu_n(f)\longrightarrow \mu(f)$ for all $f\in C_B(Y)$.

I would like to know if a sequence $\{\mu_n\}\in\mathcal{M}(Y)$ converges weak star to $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(Y)$ then $\mu_n(f)\longrightarrow \mu(f)$ is satisfied for a larger class of functions, for example functions in $L^1$.

I thank any help if as a reference.

Comment: $L^1$ is somehow ambiguous, since it refers already to a measure. So you should write $L^1(\nu),$ for some $\nu \in \mathcal{M}(Y)$. Of course you can´t expect convergence of the integrals in different measures of a function that might be integrable in only one of these measures (this is why you need boundedness of the continuous functions). What you can ask for is e.g. convergence on indicator functions. In the Portmanteau theorem tells you that you have convergence of the measures of continuity sets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_set

Comment: Just to complement on @Cornelis' fine answer: in general we can also take the Lipschitz functions. Wonderful thing that indicator functions have zero measure on the boundary say with respect to Lebesgue measure: you can then use this directly for uniquely ergodic transformations! Actually, this is a prototype of how the answer to your question is often used in ergodic theory.